# How to apply background image for a specific view in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

For my login view, i'am willing to set a specific background for it's view.

```
<body style="background-image: url('../../Content/AdminLTE/img/LogIn-BackGround.jpg');"> ...</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS is not bad
Try to make a css file inside your content with the following class

```
.login-bg { 
background-image: url('AdminLTE/img/LogIn-BackGround.jpg')
}
```

In your view add this

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/yourfile.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="login-bg">
..
</body>
```

and this a reminder about file path will help [quick-reminder-about-file-paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`background-image:url('/Content/AdminLTE/img/LogIn-BackGround.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Layout for your views so you can add a section in your _Layout like this :

```
<Html>
...
<head>
    @RenderSection( "Head",required: false )
    ....
```

Now you can add every thing you like in your html header. For example :

```
@section Head
{
   <style>
      body
      {
          background-image:url('/Images/img.jpg');
      }
    </style>
}
```

good luck